# How to achieve responsive and fast web user interface like that of native interface

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, nosql, java-ee-6

I am planning to build a web app for large data & huge traffic at real time. Input to the DB needs to be 100% fail safe from the user. It should have the same UI rendering speed as the native interface. The language platform is Java EE.

- What framework can I use and what precautions do I need to consider?
- What caching mechanism can I implement?
- Which no-sql grid db is good to use?

Answer (score 2):

You should decouple front-end (client side app) from back-end (server side Java app). Server-side app should be a JSON API (preferably RESTful) as much as possible (100%, or near that, ideally). Front-end app should use some MVC-like JavaScript framework specifically designed to build SPA (Single-Page Applications, what you want). Some popular nowadays are: Backbone.js, AngularJS, Ember.js, Knockout.js, Batman.js, etc. I've been using and loving AngularJS. Then, front-end app should communicate to JSON API via AJAX calls.

Those frameworks might seem heavyweight, but remember that nowadays browsers are very fast, with Google's V8 (also included into Node.js) as the best example. And you are building a lot of user interface logic, you need a sophisticated solution to keep your codebase maintainable.

This is a pretty much paradigm change from traditional page-refresh way to implement web apps, and it's gaining a lot of traction as the standard way to build rich internet applications nowadays. Be prepared to face the client-side app as a full-featured app, so use some kind of build solution like Grunt, or a more sophisticated and opinionated tool that leverage it, as brunch.io and yeoman.io. The next step would even be write unit tests (with Jasmine, for example).

You can implement caching on client-side app, caching JSON responses from AJAX calls, and you can cache some data in the server-side using tools like Memcached and even Redis database, very used to cache frequently accessed data, including session management.

Your last question "Which no-sql grid db is good to use?" is fairly complex and need further investigation. Nowadays there are a lot of great NoSQL solutions. I think you can start learning about the four main data models of NoSQL databases, and some of its implementations to see what fits better for your application model. For further information about that, please take a look at the article I've just published:

http://flsilva.com/blog/introduction-to-nosql

---

Answer (score 0):

From my experience ,first thoughts that come to mind would be to use a thick client - possibly leveraging Dojo.  Have as much of the presentation data served up at the start of the app as meta data and stored in the DOM. AJAX calls to do any server side functionality.  Keeping most of the processing and your meta data in the client will help keep response times down to a minimum due to less server calls